# Is it possible to get type inference for a type that allows specific string literals types OR string type

Tags: typescript, types

Consider the following type:

```js
type searchOn = 'Name' | 'ID' | string
```

I'd like the type inference for searchOn to show the options 'Name' or 'ID' but also allow any other type of string. When I add type string all type information goes away and it just resolves to type string.

I understand why it's doing what its doing but is there anyway to hold on to the type information? I'd like to provide a better developer experience by making well-known options discoverable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing comes to my mind is Enums. Type aliases [do not create a name](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases) so as you noticed developer experience may suffer. Enums do create the name so it may be easier to understand what should be used. And if you do not like the idea of additional code in your bundle you may consider using [const enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAzhCGAnAxgCwPIDsoF4oHIA5eAWwnygB8CBJAEQupmEQEtMBzAKC4kwFcSUAOoQANmIDSmAPYB3TOjDBWMzDCgBvLlCjEyuAvvIAaHVHqH89fFwC+PAGb9MyFWtgIUqABQAjEAAuTyQ0LABKLXN7Jxc3VWw-CGBgCEQAZS80fyCRcSlZBSV3dSpYFnYOSO1dGIB6OvKkYChQSCh4bCQOQT5gLjhQ30iGqADg5jZOLiSUtMyhnxHG8byJaXlFZVUNJgrOIA)